# Merge 7 node mongodb (2.4) cluster into one standalone mongo shard

Tags: mongodb, sharding

I'm running a 7 node mongodb sharded cluster (version 2.4...).

I would like to merge this into a standalone shard with 7 times the disk-space.

I've tried to create the single shard instance and running:

> db.copyDatabase('dbname', 'dbname', 'hostname_of_mongos:27017')

On it. And it starts ok, and the just hangs with no progress.

I've also tried:

> db.runCommand({
>   copydb: 1,
>   fromdb: "dbame",
>   todb: "dbname",
>   fromhost: 'hostname_of_mongos:27017'
>   })

with no succes. Can it be done, and how should I do it?

Comment: It seems that running individual db.copyDatabase against each shard, does the trick